# How to create rule for mails without any name in TO box

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

In Outlook how to create a role where no names are in the To or cc box. But I receives such mails in my inbox. I just want to filer them and move them to a separate folder.

Regards,
Alwin

Comment: Not sure if this works, but I guess you could use 2 rules. The first rules is: If anything is in To or CC, stop executing the rules. Then the 2nd rule would be: Apply to all messages, move to ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Create a new rule, do not specify any conditions (apply for all received mail)
2. Specify the required action (move to your separate folder)
3. Specify the exception "except with specific words in the recipient's address" and add the "@" character (without quotes).